# Android SQLite sort entries by frequency without grouping

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to sort the database records by row value frequency in descending order but without grouping the entries. Excuse me, I am a total beginner in databases.

Here is the full code:

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     table_name 
WHERE    date_time >= 10 
and      date_time <= 100 
GROUP BY activity_type 
ORDER BY COUNT(activity_type) DESC
```

And here is the relevant code:

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     table_name 
GROUP BY activity_type 
ORDER BY COUNT(activity_type) DESC
```

This is the desired result (sorted by the frequency of activity_type in a descending order without grouping):

```
name (irrelevant)    activity_type (number)
------------------------------------------------
Rome                       1
London                     1
Madrid                     1
Stockholm                  3
Paris                      3
Moscow                     2
```

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data?

Comment: I edited the "desired result" I hope the questine is more clear now. There are too many columns in the original database, it would only mess things up providing them here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, SQLite doesn't support `group by` in subqueries.  So your choices are either an outer join (which creates a cross product of the table by itself and which is then culled with a `group by`) or a temporary table which would contain `activity_type` counts.

```
CREATE TABLE activity_count_table(activity_type, activity_count);

INSERT INTO activity_count_table 
    SELECT activity_type, COUNT(activity_type) AS activity_count
    FROM table_name
    WHERE date_time BETWEEN 10 AND 100
    GROUP BY activity_type;

SELECT * 
FROM table_name NATURAL JOIN activity_count_table
WHERE date_time BETWEEN 10 AND 100
ORDER BY activity_count_table.activity_count DESC;

DROP TABLE activity_count_table;
```

Obviously, this is not an ideal solution.  You probably want to have some unique identifier added to the name `activity_count_table` for each call (so that multiple queries don't interfere with each other).

It's still better than creating an outer join (which needs n^2 rows in memory) and then culling it with `group by` (which really just gives you a diagonal when applied to a self-join).

Answer (score 1):

If the aggregation must not affect the actual query, you have to move it into a subquery:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE date_time BETWEEN 10 AND 100
ORDER BY (SELECT count(*)
          FROM table_name AS T2
          WHERE T2.activity_type = table_name.activity_type
            AND date_time BETWEEN 10 AND 100) DESC;
```

Comment: If SQLite supports subquery in the `ORDER BY` clause, then this is a right answer, except that you're missing the `date_time` range check in the subquery. Without it, the count will be wrong, and hence the ordering will be off.

Comment: Fixed now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your database supports it, you can use a windowing function with the `OVER` clause, e.g.

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM table_name 
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY activity_type) DESC
```

Confirmed to work on:

- MS SQL Server 2008 R2
- PostgreSQL 9.3

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately Android SQLite doesn't support it.

Comment: @TadeášBraun Perhaps if you had mentioned SQLite in your question (e.g. tagging it), we would know to limit answers to that particular RDBMS implementation.